# How can I match },{ using Regex in Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, split

I want to match `},{` and use it as a split in Eclipse and Java but I get an error on the comma.

`String[] myArray = myVariable.split("},{");` gives:

[image]

when trying to split a string like so:  `blabla},{foobar33vdhevbci` into `blabla` and `foobar33vdhevbci`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where would that be? In code or in search and replace?

Comment: That's so unclear - you just assume everyone will know what you are talking about.

Comment: Hey Dave, one thing that would help make this question clearer is to include an example of what you tried. While the question is answered for you, clarifying it will help others with the same or similar problem find answers. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks jmort253  I edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regexes have special meaning for `{` and `}`. (They denote repetition, e.g. `a{5}` means 5 a's.)

You need to escape them.

```
\},\{
```

If this is in code, as a String, make sure to escape the baskslashes

```
"\\},\\{"
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  That worked.  The question was clear for you at least!!